# Zend_Navigation vs Zend Layout

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-layout

Hi I am new to Zend Framework and using version 1.12 to start with.  I am trying to build my first site and dont know which direction to take.

I have an HTML template that I set as my Zend Layout and the navigation menu has link structured in a

Should I just create my site structure by assigning links in the layout or use Zend Navigation.

What are the benefits of using Zend Navigation?  At this point it seems much simpler to adapt the HTML to go to the controller/action than trying to format the menu created from zend navigation with css.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml file with your structure so it'll be easy to edit and keep track of. It'll add the class .active automatically to your li's. You'll have a cleaner layout script.
I mainly use it with my ACL. There is probably more reasons.